# I cant upload photo using mgp25 Instagram-Api

Tags: php, upload, instagram, instagram-api

Im using mgp25 Instagram-Api library in my projects
When i want to upload a photo i get an error: `Invalid request options`
My image is `629 x 629` pixels and jpg format.

**my code:**

```php
if($shouldProcess){
    $photo = new \InstagramAPI\Media\Photo\InstagramPhoto($target_file);
    $uploadResult = $insta->timeline->uploadPhoto($photo->getFile(), ['caption' => $caption]);
}else{
    $uploadResult = $insta->timeline->uploadPhoto($target_file, ['caption' => $caption]);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The mgp25 Instagram API is not available anymore because of *dmca takedown*.
See this -> https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API

Comment: @RaminBoodaghi in that case you should update your question to something like "mgp25 Instagram APi alternative?"
Also, as far as read about it, Facebook has exposed a Graph API which can be used to do a number of things including posting images, but that's for Business Accounts only.

Comment: To the OP: To be clear, you are asking in a public forum how to use code that was taken down because of copy right violations, and you are looking for a way to continue to use that code? Or are you asking how to perform a specific task using Instagram's official API?